# Problem with using preg_replace_callback

Tags: php, regex

i have a problem when i use preg_replace_callback. i have google translator class
and i want to translate all matches using it .

the code was .

```php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',create_function(
'$matches',
'return $translator->translate($matches);'),
$code);
```

when i make var dump for the var $code, i found its string"1" !!!

im sure that im using a right way for the class.

Thanks.

Comment: Need to see the `translate()` method. It should take only one parameter (the `$matches` array) and return a string.

Comment: Try adding `global $translator;` line, just to try...

Comment: Google Translate is going out of business this year, you shouldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is scope. Something similar to this would work in JavaScript, but JS and PHP handle scope differently. To access `$translator` from within the anonymous function's scope, you need to declare it as a global.

```
<?php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',
            create_function('$matches',
                'global $translator;'.
                'return $translator->translate($matches);'),
            $code);
?>
```

If you want to keep the anon as a one-liner, you can use the globals array:

```
<?php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',
            create_function('$matches',
                "return $GLOBALS['translator']->translate($matches);"),
            $code);
?>
```

If you have PHP 5.3.0 or later, this can be alleviated with closures and `use`:

```
<?php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',
            function($matches) use ($translator) {
                return $translator->translate($matches);
            }, $code);
?>
```

This is assuming that `$translator` was created in the same scope as `$code`.

Comment: Probably best thing is to make static function so he can access with `Translator::tranaslate($matches);`, thus avoiding global...

Comment: This is to what I just came to.

Comment: The alternative is to use a separate callback function instead of the anonymous one.

Comment: @webarto In an OOP sense I agree. I guess, though that the class creates an instance for every cURL connection to Google Translate and (since the translate function only has one argument) specifies the to and from languages. If the class were perfect it would store the connection in a static var and let a static translate function use it.

Comment: @Programmer4Me No problem. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to also pass the $translator as argument.

This could look like:

```php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',create_function(
'$translator,$matches',
'return $translator->translate($matches);'),
$code);
```

UPDATE: This code example does not work. The replace callback is invoked with only one argument while the anonymous function here expects 2 arguments. The working implementation would be:

```php
$code = preg_replace_callback('/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',create_function(
'$matches',
'global $translator; return $translator->translate($matches);'),
$code);
```

Comment: You can't pass an object as a callback. The callback must be a function.

Comment: I meant to pass the $translator as argument to the anonymous function. I will update my post to show up the code.

Comment: This does address the problem of the scope of `$translator` but not do so correctly. Since preg_replace_callback calls the callback it passes in the matches array first (and expects only one parameter).

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 5.3 you could use a Closure.

```
<?php
$code = preg_replace_callback(
    '/_e\(\'(.*?)\'\)/',
    function($matches) use ($translator) {
        return $translator->translate($matches);
    },
    $code
);
```

Comment: And in PHP 5.4 closures will be able to use instance variables again... waiting for it.